# Permanent "automatic" deinterlace in VLC in OS X

Tags: macos, video, vlc-media-player

VLC has an "Off", "On" and "Automatic" setting for deinterlace in the menu. It defaults to "Off" and the option is reset after VLC exits.

I also know that in the settings I can permanently enable deinterlacing by checking the box under Video > Filters. The option then defaults to "On".

Is there a way to permanently set this to "Automatic" on a Mac? (As ZaB points out, such an option apparently exists on other platforms in the simple settings.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In preferences you need to check "All" instead of "Basic" (in the bottom left) then navigate to Video section in the left panel, and locate the interlace option at the end of the options.

Comment: Fooled by Lion's invisible scroll bars. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have option to choose "automatic" in Simple/Video (v1.1.13 Linux).

The option adds the following to the `~/.config/vlc/vlcrc` file: (on would be `1`, off would be `0`)

```
deinterlace=-1
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The option is apparently not available in OS X, though. I'll add that to the question.